# How to persistently set a gitlab runner tag?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 2 Kubernetes instances:

- Production
- Testing

Both with a gitlab runner for CI/CD pipelines.
Since some jobs are only for `production` and others only for `testing` I tagged the runners(in `values.yaml`).

`helm get values gitlab-runner -n gitlab-runner` for the `testing` runner shows this:

```
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
gitlabUrl: https://...
runnerRegistrationToken: ...
tags: testing
```

This is not working however and I have to manually set the tag in the UI (Group > CI/CD > Runners).
The problem with this is that the servers frequently reboot, which resets tags requiring a lot of manual upkeep.

Why is the setting in `values.yaml` not working? And is there a way to set tags which persist after reboots?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I see the helm parameter `tags` is now marked as obsolete, but I cannot find a replacement configuration.

Comment: yes I found a solution. The option was nested and not on the top level.
But this is obsolete, now you can set it in the ui when connecting the runner, and it will remember the tag as far as I know

Comment: Thanks! I had then already read your comment in the GitLab forum :)
I am interested in a solution for kubernetes runners, which are redeployed to every configuration change. Going through the UI is not practical at all. Why the hell they deprecated this option? :p

Comment: I also don't find it very practical to go through the UI, but in this case I believe you only need to do it once.
When you connect the runner you get a registration token, which you put in the configuration file.
When you redeploy you keep the old token and then it keeps its tags.
I haven't had a crash as of yet to confirm that it keeps its tag though...

Comment: I ended up removing the label for k8s runners and it works like a charm.